# List iterate inside class method causing infinite loop in python

Tags: python

Hello Friends I'm a newbie to Python and trying to implement some sample code using Classes in Python. I could implement using individual functions but when I'm trying to integrate via class I'm ending up in infinite loop.

Here is the snippet of code and logic I'm reading a file where contents are like as follows:

### File input.txt contents

```
fruit  apple
animal cat
vehicle car
```

My final aim is to get output as dictionary of contents with key and value like below dict and later I want to search with keys and do processing.

```
{'fruit': 'apple', 'animal': 'cat', 'vehicle':'car'}


class FileHandler:
    def __init__(self, dbf):

        self.logger = logging.getLogger('fileHandler')
        self.thefile = open(dbf, 'r')
        print(self.thefile)
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self,type,value,traceback):
        self.thefile.close()

with FileHandler(dbf='input.txt') as fh:
     config = [line.strip() for line in (fh.thefile.readlines())]
```

Here is the class definition:

```
class GetExtract:

    def __init__(self, config_list=None, config_dict=None):
        if (config_list, config_dict) is None:
            config_list = []
            config_dict = {}
        self.config_list = config_list
        self.config_dict = config_dict
    def assign_sig(self, listin):
        self.config_list = listin
        #for item in listin:
        #   self.config_list = listin.extend(item.split())
        #print("final dict is \n", self.config_list) ## break items into list
        ## Map adjacent items as key and value 
        #for index, kvalue in enumerate(self.config_list):
        #   if index %2 == 0:
        #        self.config_dict[kvalue] = self.config_list[index+1]
        #        return self.config_dict ## create a mapping inside dict

xtemp = GetExtract()
xtemp.assign_sig(config)
```

When I try to iterate using the `for` loop inside the class it goes into an infinite loop which I have commented in the above code for.
Please advise me how to achieve my aim using classes.

Comment: You keep adding items to the list you are iterating over. Of course that'd cause infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in listin:
    self.config_list = listin.extend(item.split())
```

The object you are looping over (in this case `listin`) is being modified whithin the loop.  **Never do that.**

Comment: Could you please let me know how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Below code works for me does this code works for all cases? def assign_sig(self, listin):
        signals = []
        signal_dic = {}
        for item in listin:
            signals.extend(item.split())
        print("final dict is \n", signals)
        for index, kvalue in enumerate(signals):
            if index %2 == 0:
                signal_dic[kvalue] = signals[index+1]
        print("Final dic item are", signal_dic)

Comment: @Bhaskarvedula Writing code in a comment is not going to work. If you want to clarify your question edit it (I don't think more code is going to clarify anything though). If you have another question then ask another question.